# comma seperate 2 values in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am listing files in a directory along with their epoch time (being used on a Linux box, for centralized file management).

I'm having issues getting it to join 2 fields with a comma in between.

folder structure is

c:\temp\test
 test1.txt
 test2.txt

Expected output:

```
File: test1.txt,1518167449     
File: test2.txt,1518167449
```

i have all the information in:

```
(Get-ChildItem C:\temp\test | select name, @{name='lastwritetime';Expression={[int][double]::Parse((Get-Date $_.LastWriteTime -UFormat %s))}})
```

gives the output

```
Name        lastwritetime  
test1.txt   1518167449  
test2.txt   1518167455
```

but i'm not able to join them so they look in the correct format (with the comma join).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$Files = (Get-ChildItem C:\temp\test | select name, @{name='lastwritetime';Expression={[int][double]::Parse((Get-Date $_.LastWriteTime -UFormat %s))}})

$Files | ForEach-Object {
    "$($_.Name),$($_.LastWriteTime)"
}
```

This uses a `ForEach-Object` loop that iterates through each file and outputs a string. The string uses subexpressions `$( )` to allow us to access the two properties we want and interpolate them in the string with a comma between them.

Note that you don't have to use a `$Files` variable, you could instead chain the `ForEach-Object` command on the end of your `Select`, but because that command is already quite long this makes the code a bit cleaner.

Another option is this:

```
$Files | ForEach-Object {
    "{0},{1}" -f $_.Name,$_.LastWriteTime
}
```

Its up to you as to which you feel is more readable.

You could also consider using the `ConvertTo-CSV` cmdlet, although that will also add quote marks around each value. If your ultimate destination is CSV though using that or `Export-CSV` is cleaner/simpler.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply and help Mark , it works fine this way - currently it will be retrived from a linux machine, and added to a database ( that will be used in evaluating what logs/files that should be deleted) - instead of doing it locally